# How to display newest post from fb fanpage in inframe or something? (for HTML)

Tags: html, post, iframe

I want to put an iframe or something on my webpage with newest post posted on fanpage. I want only display newest post, with fully content. How can i do this?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. One thing that is nice to see in questions is what research has been done and any attempts that have been made to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of the page **and** have a reviewed application, you can send a request to the [GET /v12.0/{page-id}/feed HTTP/1.1](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%7Bpage-id%7D%2Ffeed&version=v12.0) endpoint and retrieve the latest post URL.

The response from that endpoint will have the following format:

```json
{
"data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2019-05-17T16:24:04+0000",
      "message": "Become a Facebook developer!",
      "id": "{page-id}_2191966997525824"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2019-02-26T21:35:42+0000",
      "message": "Hello world!",
      "id": "{page-id}_2072371269485398"
    },
...]
}
```

`id` contains both the `page-id` and the post ID. `https://www.facebook.com/{page-id}/posts/{post-id}` will be the link to the post. Take that link and leverage Facebook's [Embedded Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/) tool to generate code to display the post in an `iframe`.

Related read: [Facebook's Page Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v12.0/page/feed)

Comment: I'm not the owner of the page. There is some other solution?

Comment: If you do not own or manage the Page, you will need the [Page Public Content Access Feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS).